# Why pointer remains nullptr after initialisation

Tags: c++, pointers, binaryfiles

I wrote binary parser which reads and prints various info about file. I wish use E32ImageHeader data directly for speed reasons instead function calls.

I pass nullptr initialized variable and after function return variable remains nullptr. In GetFileLayout() gdb prints various field values for iHdr and some correctly other need revision.

Code looks correct but tools print "Header not recognized!!!", binary for test kf__speedups_SDK.pyd take [here](https://github.com/fedor4ever/elf2e32/tree/master/tests)

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "e32info.h"
#include "e32parser.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    E32ImageHeader *hdr = nullptr;
    E32Parser *parser = new E32Parser("AlternateReaderRecogE32.dll", hdr);
    parser->GetFileLayout(hdr);
    if(!hdr)
        cout << "Header not recognized!!!\n";
//    E32Info *f = new E32Info("h", "AlternateReaderRecogE32.dll");
//    f->Run();
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    delete parser;
    return 0;
}
```

binary parser header file e32parser.h:

```
#ifndef E32PRODUCER_H
#define E32PRODUCER_H

class E32ImageHeader;

class E32Parser
{
    public:
        E32Parser(const char* aFilename, E32ImageHeader *aHdr);
        ~E32Parser();
        void GetFileLayout(E32ImageHeader *result);
    private:
        void ReadFile();

    private:
        E32ImageHeader *iHdr = nullptr;

        const char *iFileName = nullptr;
        char *iBufferedFile = nullptr;
        size_t iE32Lenth = 0;
}
```

how it works
e32parser.cpp:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "e32common.h"
#include "e32parser.h"

E32Parser::E32Parser(const char* aFilename, E32ImageHeader *aHdr):
    iHdr(aHdr), iFileName(aFilename)
{
}

E32Parser::~E32Parser()
{
    delete iBufferedFile;
}
```

Read binary file to internal buffer

```
void E32Parser::ReadFile()
{
    std::fstream fs(iFileName, fs.binary | fs.in);
    if(!fs)
        throw;
    fs.seekg(0, fs.end);
    int lenth = fs.tellg();
    fs.seekg(0, fs.beg);

    iBufferedFile = new char[lenth];
    fs.read(iBufferedFile, lenth);
    fs.close();;
}

void E32Parser::GetFileLayout(E32ImageHeader *result)
{
    ReadFile();

    iHdr = (E32ImageHeader*)iBufferedFile;
    result = (E32ImageHeader*)iBufferedFile;
}
```

Comment: Because you are changing only a copy of the pointer variable. Pass it by reference if you want it to be changed.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes, the question seems fairly good to me,

Comment: @Tas not down-voter but: 2 mins worth of debugging, writing the post took longer. Missing "minimal" in [mcve]

Comment: `result = (E32ImageHeader*)iBufferedFile;` changes the parameter, but since the parameter is not a reference, it only changes it locally.  It does not change the caller's argument.

Comment: Btw, you may get rid of all that `new` with `std::vector` and/or `std::unique_ptr`/value.

Comment: When passing a pointer what's pointed at is passed by reference. The pointer itself is still passed by value.

Comment: @RichardCritten disagree a little. The writer knew exactly where the problem was and what the problem was. They just didn't know why. Debugging doesn't usually help with a problem like that. They could have reduced to an MCVE though.

Comment: Unrelated (and probably a future bug) Note: `E32Parser` does not observe [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) and is vulnerable to bad behaviour when copied deliberately or by accident. [More information on the Rule of Three and Friends](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: When you do `int i = 0; doSomething(i);` why does i remain 0 after initialisation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue, as pointed out in the comments, is that you are modifying a COPY of the pointer that you pass in. Consider this small example:

```
void modify(int* p) { p = new int{10}; }

int main()
{
    int* n = nullptr;
    modify(n);
    if (n)
        std::cout << *n;
}
```

The output of this program is nothing (and it leaks memory). `modify` doesn't change the original value, it changes a copy of `n`. The fix to this, and your program, is to pass the pointer by reference.

```
void modify(int*& p) { p = new int{10}; }
```

and

```
void E32Parser::GetFileLayout(E32ImageHeader*& result)
```

However, I'd argue a better fix is just return the pointer, to prevent this issue:

```
E32ImageHeader* E32Parser::GetFileLayout()
{
    ...
    iHdr = (E32ImageHeader*)iBufferedFile;
    return iHdr;
}
```

But since `iHdr` is passed in to `E32Parser`, you could change it to be a reference instead

Comment: Thanks a lot! E32ImageHeader* E32Parser::GetFileLayout() is more meaningful and simple variant!